# php mysql provide unique voucher

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a website that will provide vouchers (serial codes). All voucher codes generated and saved in a table like this and not generated online:

```
 v_id             voucher                status (used?)
-------------------------------------------------------
  1              abcdefgabcdefg1             0
  2              abcdefgabcdefg2             0
  3              abcdefgabcdefg3             0
  4              abcdefgabcdefg4             0
```

I should display ununsed (status:0) voucher to end user after successful payment but I am not sure how can I do this because this site may have high traffic so more than one people may visit site in same milisecond of time, so for example I can not just use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status=0 LIMIT 0,1;
```

and then UPDATE it:

```
UPDATE table SET status=1 WHERE v_id=....
```

because two people may visit in same time so we provide v_id=1 serialcode to both of them (same serial code).

what would be best way to ensure I display unique serial code?

Comment: how are the vouchers being deployed? Do they have to click to retrieve?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php 
Maybe it's can help ? It's uniq but not secure code

Comment: Is there any potential to create the vouchers one requests? This could help you deal with the possible duplication conflict?

Comment: Why would more than 1 person get a voucher code that can only be used once?

Comment: @scottevans93 no I can not generate them online.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ as I said it is possible that two people visit at the same time, so SELECT query return same result before UPDATE change status.

Comment: so basically these vourchers are pre saved to the database on creation of the app?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes

Comment: and what happens when you they are all used you go and code new ones?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I will display no more exist to sell.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Instead of having `status` column, you should have another table which is populated with used vouchers (their primary key). You place `unique` constraint and foreign key which lets only one voucher to ever be used. That's the only way you can guarantee data integrity in concurrent environment. No other way exists.

Comment: Using SQL transactions may enforce unique use, as select and update would be executed atomically, if I remember well...

Answer (score 2):

## Disclaimer

The code in this answer hasn't been tested. Every column name and table name should be adjusted to fit your code. This answer is posted to illustrate how to handle concurrency and uniqueness.

### The problem

Ensure that one voucher can be used only once

### The solution

We'll create another table which we'll fill with vouchers that have been used.

Mentioned table will have a `foreign key` to `voucher` table, referencing a particular voucher by its primary key and it will have the same column made `unique`. That makes vouchers 100% safe from being used more than once

### Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE vouchers_uised (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    voucher_id int unsigned not null,
    unique(voucher_id),
    foreign key (voucher_id) references `vouchers` (`id`) on delete cascade
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

### Logic

When a voucher is used, you have to insert into `vouchers_used` table. It's a simple table so all you need to do is insert a single column.

```
INSERT INTO vouchers_used SET voucher_id = 1;
```

### On success

If successful, PHP will interpret the result of query / prepared statement as `true`

### On failure

The failure is going to signal `SQLSTATE` with code `23000` which is code for `DUPLICATE KEY`. If you use `PDO` in exception mode, catching the exception and checking `$e->getCode() == '23000`;` will allow you to check whether query failed because voucher was used already

### How to list available vouchers

There are two ways to handle available vouchers.

First one is to attempt to `JOIN` the table with used vouchers and filter out on vouchers that **are not present** in `vouchers_used` table

Second one is to help yourself a bit with the flags that you wanted to use, `is_available` on `vouchers` table. You can aid yourself with a little trigger that updates `vouchers` table every time a record is added to `vouchers_used` table. That way you don't have to worry too much about the logic in PHP code

Trigger code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `vouchers_used_after_insert` AFTER INSERT
    ON `vouchers_used`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE vouchers SET is_used = 1 WHERE id = NEW.voucher_id;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

### Showing available vouchers

To show vouchers that are available on frontend, a simple query is sufficient:

```
SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE is_used = 0;
```

If a voucher gets used in the mean time, `unique` constraint will prevent the user from doing anything bad for data integrity. Your job is to interpret messages from database accordingly and instruct the user that voucher has been used in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "how do I fix the concurrency issue because a value could have changed between the moment I check (retrieve the current written data), the moment I take a decision (disallow/allow the use of the voucher) and the moment you actually flag the voucher as used (in case you allow it)".

Use transactions.
Check the following to make sure your database (connection) is set up correctly to use transactions:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

And just as important, the right isolation level for it to work:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

- You start a transaction which will stall further reads.
- Read the value.
- Check from it what you want
- Update the query if necassry
- Commit or rollback the transaction

SQL Code:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT v_id, status
FROM   table
WHERE  voucher = 'voucher code';

UPDATE table
SET Status = -1 #reserve
WHERE voucher = 'voucher code'
AND   Status = 0;


#handle logic to either allow or decline claim

UPDATE table
SET Status = 1 #claim
WHERE voucher = 'voucher code'
AND   Status = -1;

if (l_allow) then
   commit;
else
   rollback;
end if;
```

Alternatively you can do an update select.
Which updates a value in the database in the same query you select something.

To retrieve the result you either use local variables so you do not have request the same table again.

```
UPDATE (table a, (
    SELECT i.ID, i.Col1, @Col2 := i.Col2 
    FROM other_table) i
) TableSel
)
SET a.Col1 = TableSel.Col1,
    a.Col2 = 1
FROM (

WHERE 
    i.ID = table.ID;

SELECT @Col2;
```

Or do the update with a temporary state and select the corresponding record to see if it succeeded.

```
UPDATE table
SET Status = -1 #reserve
WHERE voucher = 'voucher code'
AND   Status = 0;

SELECT v_id, status
FROM   table
WHERE  voucher = 'voucher code';
```

You can handle the last bit in code
OR

```
SELECT if(ifnull(status, 0) = -1, 1, 0) as IsClaimed  
FROM   table
WHERE  voucher = 'voucher code';
```

However, now you have to do the claiming separately (SET status = 1)
or unset it if you want to undo this action for which ever reason.

**Update (10-02-2017)**

To be clear, what you want to achieve here is to prevent any other interactions on said table, so you prevent an incorrect read out of the current state AND prevent changes till you have figured out if you want to do something and then do the actual update/insert/delete.

With the isolation level / transaction you can achieve that to lock a table which will make other transactions wait until the deed is done.

You can also hard lock a table directly:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/

Which is a bit more tricky as a transaction expires when you either commit/rollback the transaction, close the connection or the connection gets lost (if your database server is set up accordingly).

When you lock tables by hand and do not implement some method to check periodically if a lock is kept on "to long", you will stall database operations the moment you forget to remove the lock (in your script/function/stored procedure) or a script/function fails halfway in and does not actually reach the unlock table clause.

Making this solution not really recommendable for anything else but operations for: data staging, large/full db/table transfers, large aggregation/calculations (for example for corporate reporting) and datasets (1 or more tables) that absolutely have to be complete + coherent to be of use (no sense in querying on a sensory data table from 2 jan 2017 when it is still being populated and it is required to have it complete in order to do proper deltas).

So I stand by my solution to use a function/stored procedure with a transaction when you are able to use the correct isolation level.

If your question is "How do I ensure the voucher code is unique" then you should put a unique index on your voucher column.

Which you should do anyway unless you plan to reuse voucher codes, on which you need to do some partitioning either with: enabled/disabled state, start/end date or something like a campaign.

In this last case you can ensure uniqueness by adding both fields to the unique index.

Comment: This is wrong, transactions don't ensure uniqueness, they ensure that either all queries execute successfully or not. Your code doesn't prevent concurrent users from accessing the same thing. The only way for this feature to work is to implement uniqueness on database level.

Comment: They DO when you set the isolation level correctly
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read
"For locking reads (SELECT with FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE), UPDATE, and DELETE statements, locking depends on whether the statement uses a unique index with a unique search condition, or a range-type search condition."
Like a said, if you set up prerequisites correctly, the database engine will lock further reads till the transaction is done. Thus ensuring you can check a value, make a decision, upd/ins which ever and finish.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is this - change transaction isolation level to something that makes it lock tables, which can make the whole daemon unstable (locks need unlocks, what locked it can die and now you have a cool problem). Then, instead of using proven techniques, implement your own version for checking uniqueness - a select, which, if rows are returned - "ensures" something exists. Basically, you're suggesting to turn a Boeing 747 to a guy on rollerblades and that totally sounds good to you, right? Because why use proven approach if you can screw it all up using "custom" approach.